# Putting table and image in same landscape page

Tags: tables, graphics, formatting, landscape, afterpage

I am trying to put a long table and three images in the same landscape page. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

% want to put a table and images here

\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \centering
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}

    \begin{tabularx}{0.991\linewidth}{lccccccccccc} \toprule
         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{No Clustering} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$K$-means Clustering} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Hierarchical Clustering} \\ 
         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{--} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$K=19$} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$K=5$} \\   
         \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-8} \cmidrule(l){9-12}
         % this is what has to be replaced with xtable
         & Lasso & Elastic Net & pcLasso & gLasso & ogLasso & sgLasso & pcLasso & gLasso & ogLasso & sgLasso & pcLasso \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{Parameters} & $\lambda = 0.0041$ & $\lambda = 0.0051$ & $\lambda = 0.0055$ & $\lambda = 0.0036$ & $\lambda = 0.078$ & $\lambda = 0.024$ & $\lambda = 0.0055$ & $\lambda = 0.0030$ & $\lambda = 0.078$ & $\lambda = 0.024$ & $\lambda = 0.0055$ \\ 
         & -- & $\alpha = 0.8$ & $\texttt{rat} = 1$ & -- & -- & $\alpha = 0.2$ & $\texttt{rat} = 0.9$ & -- & -- & $\alpha = 0.4$ & $\texttt{rat} = 0.95$ \\ %\addlinespace
        Misclass. & $5/36$ & $3/36$ & $2/36$ & $2/36$ & $14/36$ & $3/36$ & $2/36$ & $3/36$ & $14/36$ & $14/36$ & $2/36$ \\
        Deviance & $0.24$ & $0.083$ & $0.45$ & $0.18$ & $1.24$ & $1.46$ & $0.44$ & $0.28$ & $1.24$ & $1.46$ & $0.44$ \\
        Sig. Coef. & $14$ & $28$ & $16$ & $443$ & $1$ & $52$ & $76$ & $2714$ & $1$ & $772$ & $46$ \\
        Sig. Groups & -- & -- & -- & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $15$ & $2$ & $0$ & $1$ & $5$ \\ 
        %
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{The performance of various models on the leukemia data set.}

\end{table}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 0.48\textwidth]{img1.pdf}
    \includegraphics[width = 0.48\textwidth]{img2.pdf}
    \includegraphics[width = 0.48\textwidth]{img3.pdf}
    \caption{The ROC curves for the leukemia data set.}
    \label{leuk_ROC}
\end{figure}

\end{landscape}
}

\lipsum[3-7]

\end{document}
```

The goal is to have the table stretch across the page, and the three images line up below it. However, here is my result:

[image]

Clearly, it did not work. Any suggestions on how this can be fixed?

**EDIT**

I made some small modification to the code and changed the output. But the issue still remains.

Comment: i have the error : `LaTeX Error: File "bookmarks.sty" not found.` . Please made your code compileable.

Comment: Probably, it would be enough to use `\begin{table}[p]` and `\begin{figure}[p]`.

Comment: @AndréC sorry! I meant `booktabs` instead of `bookmarks`, I have updated the question and it compiles on my computer.

Comment: But both into thje same float and use `\captionof{type}{text}` to change the caption type of the other contents.

Comment: @daleif could you possibly elaborate more?

Comment: `\begin{table} <table contents> \caption{...} <figure contents> \captionof{figure}{...} \end{table}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replacing `[ht]` by `[p]` for both the table and the figure, I got them into one landscape page. (`draft` is added to ignore the missing images.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

% want to put a table and images here

\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[p]
    \small
    \centering
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}

    \begin{tabularx}{0.991\linewidth}{lccccccccccc} \toprule
         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{No Clustering} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$K$-means Clustering} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Hierarchical Clustering} \\ 
         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{--} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$K=19$} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$K=5$} \\   
         \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-8} \cmidrule(l){9-12}
         % this is what has to be replaced with xtable
         & Lasso & Elastic Net & pcLasso & gLasso & ogLasso & sgLasso & pcLasso & gLasso & ogLasso & sgLasso & pcLasso \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{Parameters} & $\lambda = 0.0041$ & $\lambda = 0.0051$ & $\lambda = 0.0055$ & $\lambda = 0.0036$ & $\lambda = 0.078$ & $\lambda = 0.024$ & $\lambda = 0.0055$ & $\lambda = 0.0030$ & $\lambda = 0.078$ & $\lambda = 0.024$ & $\lambda = 0.0055$ \\ 
         & -- & $\alpha = 0.8$ & $\texttt{rat} = 1$ & -- & -- & $\alpha = 0.2$ & $\texttt{rat} = 0.9$ & -- & -- & $\alpha = 0.4$ & $\texttt{rat} = 0.95$ \\ %\addlinespace
        Misclass. & $5/36$ & $3/36$ & $2/36$ & $2/36$ & $14/36$ & $3/36$ & $2/36$ & $3/36$ & $14/36$ & $14/36$ & $2/36$ \\
        Deviance & $0.24$ & $0.083$ & $0.45$ & $0.18$ & $1.24$ & $1.46$ & $0.44$ & $0.28$ & $1.24$ & $1.46$ & $0.44$ \\
        Sig. Coef. & $14$ & $28$ & $16$ & $443$ & $1$ & $52$ & $76$ & $2714$ & $1$ & $772$ & $46$ \\
        Sig. Groups & -- & -- & -- & $1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $15$ & $2$ & $0$ & $1$ & $5$ \\ 
        %
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{The performance of various models on the leukemia data set.}

\end{table}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 0.48\textwidth]{img1.pdf}
    \includegraphics[width = 0.48\textwidth]{img2.pdf}
    \includegraphics[width = 0.48\textwidth]{img3.pdf}
    \caption{The ROC curves for the leukemia data set.}
    \label{leuk_ROC}
\end{figure}

\end{landscape}
}

\lipsum[3-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]